# How to unit test build script?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, build, build-process, build-automation

I am trying to unit test my build script.

I think following testing scenarios are normal scenarios

1. Verify the build version number correctness
2. Verify version numbers of msi and verify whether they are latest?
3. Verify whether all the assemblies were strong name signed
4. verify whether compilation failures were communicated to responsible person?

What are all the other test cases may be commonly applicable for build script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "what are other test cases" - You probably want to test that it handles failures correctly - if a disk fails, if the compile fails, there's some other I/O error. Whatever your error procedures are, you should test for those.

Does your build script run your automated tests also? You might want to check that it actually runs those (getting recursive here), and reports failures from those correctly.

Testing the version numbers seems straightforward. I assume you are passing the version numbers to the script (or have some other easily identifiable way of figuring out what they should be). Check that your build artifacts have those numbers in the filename/readme/whereever.

Comment: Thanks. really useful cases. (i have added one in my question itself thought that it is very important test case will be useful for all)